# Git Bash Error: could not fork child process

Tags: bash, git, cygwin, git-bash

Git Bash was working fine until today. Now I get the following error upon launch. If I press enter it then closes:

> Error: could not fork child process: Resource temporarily unavailable
>   (-1). DLL rebasing may be required. See 'rebaseall / rebase --help'.

I've tried reinstalling, restarting, installing different versions, nothing seems to help. When googling around, all the similar issues aren't exactly the same and the answers are pretty much latin to me.

Currently running Git version 2.10.1 64 bit on Windows 7. A work computer.

GitBash screenshot

[image: Screnshot]

Comment: StackOverflow is not a bugtracker. Please bring this issue on [the project's bugtracker](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues) instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is clearly a bug; bugs belong in the project's bugtracker.

Comment: I see similar questions on stackoverflow when I google all of the time. How do you know it's "clearly a bug", it could be something I just need to run to fix it.

Comment: I don't think that this is a bug since it sounds similar to issues that I have seen for Cygwin that can be fixed by following a couple of steps.

Comment: That doesn't make it a stack overflow question; at best that makes it a superuser question

Comment: I'm okay having the question wherever it's most likely to be correctly answered. My apologies, I am not a top user of stack exchange and put it where I thought was appropriate.

Comment: @HarrisonWallace, ah, sorry, I'm following the development of GfW and subscribed to its bugtracker so I now see I'm biased in the sense I've seen quite a lot of similar issues being discussed there, and most of them are indeed bugs. I mean, if a program failed to `fork()` (to run another program or a copy of itself) it *is* bug no matter whether there may exist a set of steps to fix it or not. It's not something related to the *usage* of a program--that is, carrying out tasks when it functions in an expected way. That's what SO deals with. Hope my explanation clears things up ;-)

Comment: I appreciate it kostix, as a result of your post I did post the question on their issues page as well.

Comment: I had the same problem and managed to fix it. I've added the details to your logged issue. https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/910

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/910  https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1200.  I didn't realize until after I fixed the same problem that Goose's solution hadn't just put me on the right track -- it was actually the same solution as mine.

Answer (score -1):

l'm late,your problem caused by window system bit,if you windown system is 32bit please down git for 32bit,64bit system down git 64bit.

Comment: That is the conventional wisdom:  For 32-bit OS, download 32-bit Git for Windows; for 64-bit OS, download 64-bit OS.  However, this user already has 64-bit Git for Windows installed, and presumably has a 64-bit OS.  The documentation on github says "The simplest solution to fix that problem if it rears its ugly head at all is to switch to the 64-bit version of Git for Windows (the 64-bit address range is so large that MSYS2's runtime virtually never has any run-in with another .dll)," but in fact address conflicts are still possible with 64-bit Git for Windows.